# Задание с кортежами

Tags: python, анализ-данных, tuple

- Заполнить один кортеж десятью целыми числами от 0 до 5 включительно.
- Второй кортеж - числами от -5 до 0.
- Объедените оба кортежа при помощи оператора "+", создав таким образом третий кортеж.
- При помощи метода кортежа `count()` определите, сколько в нем нулей.
- Выведите на экран третий кортеж и количество нулей в нем.

```
tuple(random.randint(0,5) for i in range(10))
```

не работает...

Comment: Я не смог зделать именно все.Я не смог зделать tuple(random.randint(0,5) for i in range(10))

Comment: Чтобы оно делалось рандомно

Comment: `a = tuple(random.randint(0, 5) for i in range(10))` работает же ж... что не смогли сделать? `import random` не забыли?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

a = tuple(random.randint(0, 5) for i in range(10))
b = tuple(random.randint(-5, 0) for i in range(10))
c = a + b

print(c)
print(c.count(0))
```

выведет (у вас будет другой результат):

```
(4, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 1, -4, -3, -5, -5, -1, -5, -3, -2, -5, -5)
2
```

ps как варианы распаковки в кортеж:

```
a = tuple([random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(10)])
```

или (запятая в конце - обязательна)

```
a = *(random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(10)),
```

pps разницы в скорости особо нет:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

```
$ python3 -m timeit "import random; a = *(random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(10)),"
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.6 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit "import random; a = tuple([random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(10)])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.7 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit "import random; a = tuple(random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(10))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.9 usec per loop
```